# How to use > in SQL with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, database

Doing some coursework for university but have been having trouble trying to use  '>' as my WHERE condition should be `WHERE COUNT > 18` but it doesn't seem to work, i realise the solution is probably very easy but i cant seem to figure it out

```
SELECT Company_name, COUNT(1) as cc
FROM
Customer JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref
JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
GROUP by Company_name
```

Comment: `HAVING` is what you are looking for. Use when you need to filter on aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply condition on a group in where clause, you have to use HAVING:

```
SELECT Company_name, COUNT(1) as cc
FROM Customer 
JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref
JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
GROUP by Company_name
HAVING cc > 18;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `HAVING`:

```
GROUP BY Company_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 18
```